# Failure to force type on java generic

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a complete stumper, and pose it to all of you to see if you know whats going on.

This is the data structure

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap
```

it stores Strings and Numerical values for now, but may store more types in the future.

This is the function I'm using to retrieve those values:

```
public <T> T get(String variable, T defaultValue) {
    // returns either the object from the map, or the default if its not in the map.
    Object value = getObject(variable, defaultValue); 
    logger.debug("default value is of type " + defaultValue.getClass().getName());

    // Attempt to get around casting issue
    if (value instanceof Number)
    {
        value = (Number) value;
    }
    T ret = (T) value;
    logger.debug("Variable " + variable + " which is of type " + value.getClass().getName() + " and returning as " + ret.getClass().getName() + " (is number: " + (value instanceof Number) + ")");

    return ret;
}
```

And this is the calling code:

```
public int getFoo() { return this.<Integer>get("foo", 0); }
```

This is the output i see in the logs:

```
default value is of type java.lang.Integer
Variable foo which is of type java.lang.Long and returning as java.lang.Long (is number: true)
```

Right before it fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

What concerns me the most here is that **the class type appears to be Long, despite attempting to force the class to using Integer**.

Am i missing something, or violating some concept of Java generics?

Thanks for any help

Comment: For starters, you really shouldn't be using a `Map<String, Object>`.  Maps should have a single, specific value type and it's really code-smelly to be mixing them together.

Comment: please send more stack trace, where this exception occurred?

Comment: What does the put to the map look like?

Comment: Obviously `getObject` returns Long. You didn't give a description of this function.

Comment: Where `put` method of `map` called?

Comment: maybe return value of this method be reason of exception.

Comment: - Louis, i agree, this was an attempt to work around porting code from another language.
- The exception occured iwthin the getFoo() function, trying to cast to an int.
- Yes, its obvious the return value is the problem.  
- The put was left out intentionally because it has little bearing on what i'm trying to do, which was to take a potentially random number type and cast it to a type determined by the caller.
- The description of getObject is listed in the comment directly above the call - it is essentially a get, returning an alternate value if that get returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by the `getObject` method is a `java.lang.Long` - the log is telling you that.

Generics are not magic, they will not convert between types, they're simply syntactic sugar that the compiler turns back into casts.  So your method:

```
public <T> T get(String variable, T defaultValue)
```

is really:

```
public Object get(String variable, Object defaultValue)
```

When the get method is invoked with:

```
this.<Integer>get("foo", 0)
```

this is really:

```
(Integer)this.get("foo", 0)
```

Hence the ClassCastException because the `Object` being returned is a `Long`, not an `Integer`.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's hard to give concrete advice but generally your `Map` should be using the generic type that you are expecting to deal with.  In your case this sounds like either `Integer` or `Number`.  If you really want the int value of any `Number` (which I doubt because the value will be truncated when it's bigger than an int) then you should use the `Number.intValue()` method.

Comment: This was the anser I was looking for.  I thought this.<Integer> forced the type in the function to become integer, rather than becoming a cast.

Comment: When the call is being executed, this.<Integer>get("foo", 0)
 gets translated to (Integer)this.get("foo", 0). But even dynamically this cast is less then what is performed by generics: there can be further casts within the method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Java type-erasure. Java typing is only used in source code. The compiler converts the code just like if you would have cast all objects. If you get a Long value, it means that you put it as a Long value.

This code does not perform anything:

```
if (value instanceof Number)
{
    value = (Number) value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the key "foo" in your backing map is obviously of type Long. You cannot cast a Long to an Integer (even if both are of type Number - and both are of type Object ;)

If you want to force an Integer, you have to do it when putting the value for "foo" into the map.